# undefined method specs for :"https://rubygems.org":Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

Trying to follow this tutorial

http://chickenboot.com/2013/05/18/zurb-foundation-with-nanoc-part-1/

using rails on windows.

Once I get to this part

```
bundle exec compass install foundation -c compass.rb
```

I get this error

http://tinypic.com/r/14kxpp4/5 (also shown below):

[image]

Not sure what this means, I've looked for a solution and I'm stumped. Any suggestions? I just want to get foundation-rails installed on my rails nanoc site.

Answer (score 3):

I added a response to your comment on the blog, but just for anyone that finds it here - I can recreate this error by making the first line of my Gemfile:

```
source :"https://rubygems.org"
```

You should be fine if you remove the colon. It changes the type of the string to a Symbol, and bundler treats a Symbol differently than a string.

You can change it to either:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

or

```
source :rubygems
```

Though you will get a warning about not using https on the latter.